# How to send sms programmatically in background without open sms popup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to send SMS functionality in background without open popup for SMS

any framework or SDK for that

I have used `CTMessageCenter` (`CoreTelephony` Framework) but not working

code:

```
BOOL success =  [[CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter] sendSMSWithText:@"test 1234..." serviceCenter:nil toAddress:@"+1234567890" withMoreToFollow:NO];

    if(success){
        NSLog(@"Message SENT");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Message not SENT");
    }
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: This is not possible with the Public SDK of iOS. Just imagine that some spam app will send 1000 of SMS to a paid service without the user known it.

Comment: is it possible to send sms in background without open popup for sms?

Comment: Again NO, just repeating you question will not change the outcome. There is not way to send a SMS in an app that you want submit for the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't allow sending SMS or email without user interaction, even you do with trick, it will be rejected